# Room DB insert callback

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have an app with MVP pattern and I use Room DB to insert, update, delete, get data. I don't use LiveData still.

Is there any way I can get a callback when I insert or delete data.

I use Coroutines and for get data from DB, I use Deferred for promise resolver and do await() something like this -

```
val deferredResult = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { roomDao?.getPetList() }
return deferredResult.await()
```

But how do I do it for insert or delete since I don't get any callback from Room

Comment: If you upgrade to `androidx.room:room-ktx:2.2.0-alpha02`, you can have `getPetList()` return a `Flow` instead of `Deferred`. That `Flow` will deliver fresh results for your query whenever you modify the contents of the database.

Comment: Ah cool thank you, I will try it out